# PHP JQuery Autocomplete background

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jquery UI to do autocomplete for my textbox, the autocomplete is working fine with this code

```
$(function() {
    $("#company_name").autocomplete({
        source: "{{URL::to('category')}}",
        autoFocus:true
    });
});
```

but the problem is my autocomplete suggesion dont have background like white background.. how to fix it?

Comment: In the jQueryUI stylesheet....

Comment: Change the/add #company:focus{background-color: you color} css. But your browser might do something here as well. What browser do you use? Is it in all browsers?

Comment: i'm using Mozilla Firefox, i try use your css code but it's not work.. my textbox background changed, but the autocomplete list is not